# how to install libgnutls26 in Ubuntu 15.04 or higher

Tags: software-installation

I am having problem installing `libgnutls26`. I tried searching but didn't helped. I am using 32 bit sys. While installing a program it says following :

```
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.14-0)
```

I tried installing with gdebi but it also didn't helped. Can anyone help me to fix it? BTW my Ubuntu is 15.04.

Comment: Try  `sudo apt-get install libgnutls26:i386`

Comment: I already tried that one. it says

E: Package 'libgnutls26' has no installation candidate.

I think I need to add repo but which one I dont know

Comment: what do you get when you type `apt-cache policy libgnutls26` ?

Comment: This is what I get :

libgnutls26:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

Comment: The program's dependencies appear to be targeted at Ubuntu 14.04: in 15.04 the main GNU TLS runtime library is [libgnutls-deb0-28](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libgnutls-deb0-28)

Comment: It says libgnutls-deb0-28 is already the newest version

Comment: So? that won't help if the "program" you are trying to install wants libgnutls26

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I see you point. In my case, after updating to Ubuntu 15.04 my Evernote (running on Wine 1.7.44) stopped working - when trying to log in or to synchronize notes I've been receiving `INTERNET_SECURITY_CHANNEL_ERROR` from TLS. I believe that might be due to libgnutls API change - in Ubuntu 14.10 its version was **libgnutls26** (based on GnuTLS 2.12), while in 15.04 it's **libgnutls-deb0-28** (based on GnuTLS 3.3).

If you want to install 32-bit `libgnutls26` (from Ubuntu 14.10) in Ubuntu 15.04 try these:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnutls26/libgnutls26_2.12.23-15ubuntu2_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgnutls26_2.12.23-15ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Other mirrors you can find [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libgnutls26) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libgcrypt11).

After installing these by myself, when I call `lsof -P -T -p $(pidof Evernote.exe) | grep gnutls` while running Evernote I get:

```
Evernote. 11332 xxx  mem    REG                8,6   805808  1052438 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.22.6
Evernote. 11332 xxx  mem    REG                8,6  1306528  1052404 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls-deb0.so.28.41.0
```

which means that Evernote/Wine is currently using `libgnutls26` library.

Bare in mind that you won't receive any security updates for `libgnutls26` as it has been released for 14.10, but removed completely from Ubuntu 15.04.

---

**Editor's Note**

Since 15.04 is not a LTS release, these can disappear (indeed those did). So, you should find and install from last LTS version i.e. Trusty 14.04. Find the two libraries from these two links:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libgnutls26/download (libgnutls26)
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libgcrypt11/download (libgcrypt11)

Comment: It seems that the links for Trusty 14.04 are now dead too. I might be ok though, I was trying to install a very old BricsCAD13, I will just try a newer BricsCAD.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for libgnutls.so.26 on 16.04, I fixed it by copying 14.04 lib in to 16.04

You can find the version for 14.04 from here

- 32bit - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libgnutls26/download
- 64bit - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libgnutls26/download

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main`
 to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install libgbutls26`

Comment: you might `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32`